What is meant by this association of the universe $V$ and the set of all formulas $\mathcal{L}^{(B)}$?
Reading J. L. Bell's Set Theory --- Boolean-Valued Models and Independence Proofs. The author introduces the class $V^{(B)}$, defined by
$$x \in V^{(B)} \iff \mathrm{Fun}(x) \land \mathrm{ran}(x) \subseteq B \land \mathrm{dom}(x) \subseteq V^{(B)},$$
where $B \in V$ is a Boolean algebra and $V$ is the set-theoretic universe. Now the author says:

We now introduce a first-order language suitable for making statements about $V^{(B)}$. Let $\mathcal{L}^{(B)}$ be the first-order language obtained from $\mathcal{L}$ by adding a name
for each element of $V^{(B)}$. For convenience we agree to identify each element of $V^{(B)}$ with its name in $\mathcal{L}^{(B)}$. By coding the formulas of $\mathcal{L}^{(B)}$ as sets in $V$ in the usual way, it is clear that the collection of formulas of $\mathcal{L}^{(B)}$ becomes a definable class.

What does this last sentence mean? Any clue what the "usual way" is? I understand everything that was said before.

Formulas are a simple mathematical object, and like any such thing, there are a number of straightforward ways to encode formulas in set theory.
This is spelled out concretely at one point or another in a lot of set theory books, because at some point we need to study models of (various fragments and extensions of) ZFC and in order to talk about a structure satisfying some sentences/theories, of course we need to have a representation of these things. It also is introduced sometimes in the study of the constructible hierarchy or HOD, as there are convenient definitions of these that are "logical" in nature, so involve talking about formulas / satisfaction /etc.
A typical coding scheme can be sketched as follows: let $(0,n)$ stand for the n'th variable, given an $a\in V^B,$ let $(1,a)$ stand for $a$ (as a parameter). Let $(2, x)$ be the negation of $x$, let $(3,x,y)$ be the conjunction of $x$ and $y$, and let $(4,n, x)$ be $\exists v_n$ applied to $x$.
As for the rest of the sentence, all it's saying is that, using some coding like this, you can make a formal recursive definition (say, in ZF, with the structure $B$ as a parameter) of what it means for a given set to represent a $\mathcal L^B$-formula. (By analogy, note the definition that you write down shows $V^B$ is a definable class in this sense.)

I realize now I completely forgot about atomic formulas, so I guess that’s “left as an exercise”.
